# Split vertical panel when horizontal split exists in session

Tags: conemu

I often use the following layout whilst working. My issue is that I can't seem to resize the `Main` window located in the center. I know the hot keys required to do so, however am still unable to accomplish this. I am able to resize panels 1, 2, 3, and 4, but only horizontally.

```
--------------------------
|  1  |            |  3  |
|-----|    Main    |-----|
|  2  |            |  4  |
--------------------------
```

How can resize the `Main` panel vertically?

Comment: Main does NOT have vertical splits. Obviously there is nothing to "resize".

Comment: Alright, I understand that now. How can I widen Main, then? So say I widen it to the left, then panels 1 and 2 would shrink in width.

Comment: There is a bug restricting that. Will be fixed.

Comment: Gotcha. Nonetheless, ConEmu is phenomenal. Thank you.

Comment: Haha cool I was looking at the same issue. A comment from yesterday. Thanks Max!